# filter() in R not printing in for loop?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am very new to R so what I am asking may be impossible. I am working on a project for a class in school and I am trying to print things from a *.csv* file using the `filter()` function. Here is my code:

```
mylines <- c(9, 8, 10, 3, 2, 4, 6, 1, 1, 9, 2, 3, 1, 6)
sonnet_print_vector <- function(user_vector){
  for (i in 1:length(user_vector)){
    filter(sonnets, sonnet==user_vector[i], line==i)
  }
}
sonnet_print_vector(mylines)
```

Where the data set `sonnets` is an imported .csv file of the form:

```
sonnet  line text                                                    
    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                                                   
 1      1     1 King Carlos turns his coat for better fees              
 2      1     2 and sleeves are wrapped round horns of buffalo          
 3      1     3 that tinned hornedbeef we stored smells more like cheese
```

where there are 10 sonnets each with 14 lines.

The numbers in the vector `mylines` are used to pick which sonnet the desired line will be pulled from. I am trying to print this out line-by-line to get a completely new sonnet.

Comment: You `filter(.)` but immediately discard its results. Do you intend to reassign back to `sonnets`?

Comment: Side point: use `seq_along(user_vector)` in place of `1:length(user_vector)`. In the default case it does exactly the same thing, but if you ever accidentally pass an empty vector, then `1:length(.)` will produce a vector of length 2, which is not what you want/need here.

Comment: Nothing will print inside a for loop unless you actually `print()` it.

Comment: @r2evans I am trying to simply print out all the values (one after another on a new line).

Comment: Then explicitly use print